# Getting a custom view of Twitter and Facebook posts

Tags: 7, views, feeds, social-network

I would like to display my client's twitter and facebook posts in a most-recent format in a custom view or block that will be implemented on their site. I was thinking of using the Feeds module, but was told by someone on twitter that cURL was the way to go. Giving these elements custom styling and keeping them listed by timestamp (not type of aggregate) is very important to me, and I was wondering about how to get this done.

Answer (score 2):

I have clients who require exactly the same feature, and the best method I have found so far is using [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Feeds XPath Parser](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser).

I create two Feeds importers that import from the RSS feeds of the client's Twitter and Facebook profiles. I set Feeds to create a node for each update (content type 'Social update') and use Feeds XPath Parser to populate the correct fields (title, body, timestamp, etc). I also set Feeds to automatically purge imported nodes after two weeks, and set it to schedule import on cron every hour.

Now I have each new post in a node, and I can display them however I like using Views.

This works ok, BUT I'm not convinced it's an optimal solution. I've looked at modules that interface with the Twitter and Facebook APIs for a better solution (e.g. [Twitter Pull](http://drupal.org/project/twitter_pull), [Facebook Pull](http://drupal.org/project/facebook_pull), [Feeds Facebook Parser](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_facebook), [Twitter](http://drupal.org/node/430658)) but they don't seem to provide a method for pulling Tweets and Facebook posts together in a single view or block. I'd love to get some more ideas on this.

Comment: I got the twitter feed working using Feed Aggregrator and Views. However, I can't seem to wrap my head around the facebook Social Graph API. From what I have learned, Facebook no longer supports RSS feeds since they changed to the timeline and now require setting up using their API. I'm sure I could figure it out if I could only get the FB feed...

Comment: Interesting to know. My client's Facebook RSS feeds are still working, but Facebook don't promote this service and could terminate it any time. So yep - all the more reason to go the API route if possible.

Comment: This might help http://drupal.org/project/feeds_facebook

Comment: I took a look at the feeds_facebook module and it seems like a good option. Only problem I am having is how to get the access_token for the FB API. The documentation is great, but not very organized into use cases. Any idea how to get this?

Comment: Interesting development. I got the access_token for the status and feed of my clients Facebook wall and used the feeds_facebook module with Feed aggregator to try and figure out a solution. What I have now is this URL in the feed aggregator: [https://graph.facebook.com/facebook_id/statuses?access_token=The_Access_Token]

This feed works in a new window,but generates this error in Drupal: "The feed from Facebook seems to be broken, because of error "Not well-formed (invalid token)" on line 1."

Comment: Over a year late, but still wanted to give an update. I solved this problem by moving my client's posts to a organization page in FB. Since you are unable to "Like" personal pages in Facebook, that was the problem we were running into. After I migrated my clients activity to a Organization page, I was able to use the Tokens along with the FB APIs and get this working. A stupid oversight, but wanted to share. I also hand rolled my own solution for the Twitter Feed by writing some terrible PHP code. :)